Power BI REST API returning 204 No Content after 10 successful requests in Azure App Services
I'm encountering an issue with the Power BI REST API in my .NET 8 application hosted on Azure App Services. The API endpoints, specifically related to Power BI embedding, return a status code of 204 No Content after 10 successful requests, while in localhost, it consistently returns a status code of 200 OK.
The application integrates with the Power BI REST API to embed reports and dashboards. However, after approximately 10 successful embedding requests, subsequent requests result in a 204 No Content status code, indicating that the server successfully processed the request but is not returning any content.
This behavior is inconsistent with the expected functionality, and I suspect there may be some throttling or rate-limiting mechanism at play. I'm unsure how to diagnose and resolve the issue within the context of Azure App Services.
How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue with the Power BI REST API in my .NET 8 application hosted on Azure App Services?

Here are the steps that you can follow for troubleshooting the "204 No Content" issue with Power BI REST API:
Invalid Authentication:

Verify the correctness of App Workspace ID and App Key.
Ensure they possess the required permissions.
For Azure Active Directory (AAD) token-based authentication: Validate the token's correctness.
Ensure it has the necessary permissions.

Missing or Incorrect Parameters:

Check for the presence and accuracy of Embed Token: Ensure it grants requisite permissions and resources.
Report ID: Confirm it corresponds to an existing report in Power BI.

Resource Not Found:

Ensure the requested resource exists and verify the presence and access permissions of Report or Dashboard and the Workspace.

By following these steps, you can effectively troubleshoot and resolve the "204 No Content" issue encountered with the Power BI REST API.
Also, Power BI has rules on how many times you can use its APIs in a certain time period. These rules might change depending on your Power BI plan or capacity that you have.
To understand this better, please go through the following documentations:

powerbi - Power BI API Limits - Stack Overflow
What is Power BI Premium? - Power BI | Microsoft Learn.

